# Feeds: solution with most frequent/real time/push notification update of feeds (e.g. for twitter tweets)?

Tags: 7, notifications, feeds

Which module (or solution) provides the quickest update of feeds after their source is updated? E.g. with Twitter if a new tweet is posted, which Drupal feed or twitter solution updates the quickest following that tweet? (I'd also be looking for general feed solutions for youtube etc).

I currently use feed aggregator which has minimum refresh interval of 15 minutes.

Do solutions require/work better if linked to a cron task?

Are there any real time genuine (i.e. not pseudo*) *push* notification solutions out there? Please give examples for particular feeds (e.g. twitter, youtube etc.) *by pseudo I mean a high frequency polling solution that appears to be near real time but is actually a pull on the feed from the drupal site rather than a push from the feed source.

Can feed sources like twitter be configured to *know* about subscribed external sites such that they can push updates to them?

By the way, currently evaluating the following as part of a solution for e.g. twitter (any specific advice on these welcome as is general advice on other solutions including for other feed sources such as youtube).

- http://drupal.org/project/twitter
- http://drupal.org/project/oauth
- http://drupal.org/project/twitter_pull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Twitter's "[Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview)" is your solution. However, I would look closely at their Pre-Launch Checklist before going down that route. They have 10+ things that you should comply with before becoming a stream or push consumer of their API.

Maybe a solution that would fit you is to develop a twitter stream client (that would be your server), and then to have your application users connect to your server via node.js, since node.js provides a "persistent" connection suitable for chat rooms and push-like notifications.

This is an interesting (and probably doable) suggestion, but not something that you would find pre-packaged in a Drupal module.

Comment: +1 Thanks @amateur barista. I will explore your options before accepting an answer. Good to see an application of node.js as a means to maintaining persistent connections. Distilled from the all the hype around it when all I could see was yet another server-side scripting language.

Comment: Accepted answer - the suggestions comes closest to a real time solution I was looking for. Alternatively, if I don't need that instantaneous requirement then my own original suggestions would suffice.